# use-package, way to execute :custom or :config block?

Tags: use-package, customize

`:custom` block is not executable format such as
  `(org-babel-confirm-evaluate nil)`.

whereas `(setq org-babel-confirm-evalulate nil)` can be excuted via `C-x C-e`.

Is there a way to execute a `:custom` block somehow?

Also, it would be convenient to execute `:config` block manually to see the code I write works as intended without reloading the module from scratch

Comment: Although it is not exactly equivalent, you could try using `M-x pp-macroexpand-last-sexp`, and then only evaluate the parts that more or less correspond to the `:custom:` and `:config` values (I think they are forms starting with `custom-theme-set-variables` and `progn`).

Answer (score 0):

It seems, just rerunning the whole use-package block reruns the `:config` as well

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24909)